# anchor tag a page in spree rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I have a rails app running with spree.

To the header of my app, I want to link the page to a specific page. I am using default spree app and then doing modification on the UI part.

So this is what my header is, `<li><a href="#">Black Tea</a></li>`

Now I want this to take me  to `t/categories/clothing` this path of default spree.

This page is a partial under `spree/shared_products_html.erb`.

I am not sure how can I do that.

Please help.

Comment: Not sure what you want to achieve. Why don't you simply set it as:
`<li><a href="/t/categories/clothing">Black Tea</a></li>`

Comment: oops, Thanks, I thought this won't work